# How to calculate the exact area of three 1 km buffers that have been intersected?

Tags: arcmap, buffer, overlapping-features

I am trying to figure out the exact area of overlap of the 1 km buffers around three survey posts. I have used the Intersect tool to produce three individual intercepts which cover all the overlap of the buffer (see image below). I then used the merge tool to merge these three individual intersects into one. Then, I used to calculate Geometry to calculate the total area of overlap in km2. However, the area generated was different from what I was expecting. Did creating three separate intersects lead to counting part of the overlap more than once? [image: Three intercepts of the overlap]

Comment: As stated in the previous question, Intersect causes data loss. What you really want is Union.  But that's only the first step, because then you need to go back and encode the duplicates with which sources they shared *before* removing them.  If the source buffers were in different layers, this step wouldn't be necessary. I'm working on a better solution to the first question, but I'm about to lose network connectivity for six hours, so it won't be posted for a while.

Comment: Okay. Thanks very much for your help. I will look into the Union tool.

Comment: You were right, it was the Union tool I needed. I've got the correct area of the overlap now. Thanks very much for your help!